# Prevent File.WriteAllText to write double Byte-Order Mark (BOM)?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

In the following example, if (string) text starts with a BOM, File.writeAllText() will add **another one**, writing **two BOMs**.

I want to write the text two times:

1. Without a BOM at all
2. With a single BOM (if applicable to the encoding)

What is the canonical way to achieve this?

```
HttpWebResponse response = ...
Byte[] byte = ... // bytes from response possibly including BOM 

var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(
                    response.get_CharacterSet(),
                    new EncoderExceptionFallback(),
                    new DecoderExceptionFallback()
               );
string text = encoding.GetString(bytes); // will preserve BOM if any
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, text, encoding);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decoding and then reencoding the file... It is quite useless.

Inside the `Encoding` class there is a `GetPreamble()` method that returns the preamble (called BOM for utf-* encodings), in a `byte[]`. Then we can check if the `bytes` array received has already this prefix or not. Then based on this information we can write the two versions of the file, adding or removing the prefix when necessary.

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet, new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderExceptionFallback());

// This will throw if the file is wrongly encoded
encoding.GetCharCount(bytes);

byte[] preamble = encoding.GetPreamble();

bool hasPreamble = bytes.Take(preamble.Length).SequenceEqual(preamble);

if (hasPreamble)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes("WithPreambleFile.txt", bytes);

    using (var fs = File.OpenWrite("WithoutPreamble.txt"))
    {
        fs.Write(bytes, preamble.Length, bytes.Length - preamble.Length);
    }
}
else
{
    File.WriteAllBytes("WithoutPreambleFile.txt", bytes);

    using (var fs = File.OpenWrite("WithPreamble.txt"))
    {
        fs.Write(preamble, 0, preamble.Length);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But am I correct you cannot see whether the byte-array is valid according to the encoding? That's at least why I used ```Encoding.getString(bytes)```...

Comment: @Exceptione Yes... You can't if written that way... let me modify it a little.

Comment: @Exceptione Modified. Note that in general `GetCharCount()`  is faster than `GetString()` because it doesnt't have to generate a string (and allocate memory to do it) but only count the characters

Comment: Great, neat trick with ```GetCharCount()```. I think MS should provide an ```Encoding.IsValid(Byte[] bytes)``` method, don't you think so? Thx, will try to implement it your way!